# find out values / elements of a certain range of an array

Tags: java

I would like to find out if there is a java function that can check the values from index 0-5? For example. Without using a loop Is there a function that identifies the elements in sub Array1 [0-5] as { 1,2,3,4,5}                                                                                    `int Array1[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 }`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "check" or "identify"? Check for what? Do you want to compare two arrays?

Comment: Hint: you learn programming by ... trying things yourself first. Also note that your question isnt really clear. When you are asking for library methods that would do that ... why would you care whether they use a loop? If you are asking how to WRITE such a method, as said: why don't you try it yourself first? (hint: the answer could be to use recursion instead of a flat for loop instead)

Comment: and note: learn about java naming conventions. variable names start lower case in java. And there is really no point in using the TYPE of the variable in the name. So: `int numbers[] = { 1, 2, ...};` is what you should be using for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, end)` this will return you an array containing the specified range from the original `arr` array.

`start` is inclusive, `end` is exclusive

e.g. for your case

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
int[] subArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use arrays.  Lists are easier to use.  Especially if you want to work with sub arrays since there is no copying using lists.  The `sublist` is a constrained view of the original list (it's the same list with modified start and ending indices).

```
List<Integer> intList = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
List<Integer> intSublist = list.subList(0,5);

System.out.println(intSublist.equals(List.of(1,2,3,4,5)));
```

prints

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more then one way to do this but this could be one of it:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

//starts everytime by element 0
int[] subArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 5);
```

or this

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
int[] subArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0,5);
```

but end the end they use `System.arraycopy(...)` so you can use this directly:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
int[] subArr = new int[5];

//starts at the specified index here 0
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, subArr, 0, subArr.length);
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the assistance.

Comment: @damudread so you have you answer? That's nice and pls close the question by accepting any answer